# Why is my MV unable to converge when normal Vars can?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am developing a model for a power grid. I am at the phase now where I need to put in power plant ramp rates. In my model it converges in like 2 seconds when I have Gas as an m.Var, as soon as I change it to an m.MV it can't find a solution. I am trying to change it to an m.MV so that I can limit its ramping ability. In the model the max it actually ramps is around 1900 but I was only going to limit it to 3000. Is there another type of variable that would work better? is there any reason why it can't converge as an m.MV?

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


"""
Max capacities based on MISO South Grid, Prices are currently based
google averages for a power source but will be specific to Miso soon
"""

nhrs = 240
Gas_cap = 23000  # MW
Gas_start = 18771  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Gas_cost = 38  # $/MW
Gas_min = 5000  # MW

Coal_cap = 6500  # MW
Coal_start = 962  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Coal_cost = 76  # $/MW
Coal_min = 900  # MW

Hydro_cap = 500  # MW
Hydro_start = 500  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Hydro_cost = 21  # $/MW
Hydro_min = 50  # MW

Nuc_cap = 5500  # MW
Nuc_start = 5375  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Nuc_cost = 20  # $/MW
Nuc_min = 2800  # %capacity

Other_cap = 1000  # MW
Other_start = 859.3  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Other_cost = 10  # $/MW
Other_min = 100  # MW

query = """SELECT "Actual_Load_MWh", Date_Time FROM "Load_By_Region"
            WHERE Region = "South"
                AND Date_Time BETWEEN date('2018-01-01') and date('2018-12-31')
                """

con = create_engine('sqlite:///../../../../data/MISO_data.db')
Miso_data = pd.read_sql(query, con)
load_data = pd.to_numeric(Miso_data['Actual_Load_MWh']).values[:nhrs]

date = Miso_data['Date_Time'].values[:nhrs]
Time = np.arange(len(date))
# plt.plot(Time, load_data)

m = GEKKO()
m.time = Time

load = m.Param(load_data)

Nuc = m.MV(value=Nuc_start, lb=Nuc_min, ub=Nuc_cap)
Nuc.DMAX = 1413  # MW from MISO Ramp rates
Gas = m.Var(value=Gas_start, lb=Gas_min, ub=Gas_cap)
#Gas.DMAX = 3900 # MW from MISO Ramp rates
Coal = m.MV(value=Coal_start, lb=Coal_min, ub=Coal_cap)
Coal.DMAX = 2146  # MW from MISO Ramp rates
Hydro = m.MV(value=Hydro_start, lb=Hydro_min, ub=Hydro_cap)
Hydro.DMAX = 209  # MW from MISO Ramp rates
Other = m.MV(value=Other_start, lb=Other_min, ub=Other_cap)
Other.DMAX = 605  # MW from MISO Ramp rates

slack = m.Var(lb=0)
Cost = m.Var(value=0)
CostMWh = m.Var(value=0)
# Gasramp = m.Var(value=0)

# m.Equation(Gasramp == Gas.dt())
m.Equation(load == Nuc + Gas + Coal + Hydro + Other + slack)
m.Equation(Cost == Nuc*Nuc_cost + Gas*Gas_cost + Coal*Coal_cost +
           Hydro*Hydro_cost + Other*Other_cost + slack*1e8)
m.Equation(CostMWh == Cost/load)
m.Obj(Cost)
m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()
```

Comment: Could you edit the code to fill in the missing details like the constraints, `Time`, and other things that are missing?

Comment: I just added that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't run your exact case because I don't have access to the database you are using. Below is a self-contained problem that converges to an optimal solution. This won't help because you are having a problem with your dataset. Here are a few tips on using the `m.MV()` model.

- Initialize the model with simulation before optimizing. This is possible by setting `m.options.COLDSTART=2` with `m.solve()` and then `m.options.COLDSTART=0` and `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0` (to not update the initial conditions) with another `m.solve()`. The `MV` model has [additional equations](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerObjective) that solve better when initialized.
- Here is a reference for more [tips on initialization](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135415001179):

  - Safdarnejad, S.M., Hedengren, J.D., Lewis, N.R., Haseltine, E., Initialization Strategies for Optimization of Dynamic Systems, Computers and Chemical Engineering, Vol. 78, pp. 39-50, DOI: 10.1016/j.compchemeng.2015.04.016.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

"""
Max capacities based on MISO South Grid, Prices are currently based
google averages for a power source but will be specific to Miso soon
"""

nhrs = 240
Gas_cap = 23000  # MW
Gas_start = 18771  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Gas_cost = 38  # $/MW
Gas_min = 5000  # MW

Coal_cap = 6500  # MW
Coal_start = 962  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Coal_cost = 76  # $/MW
Coal_min = 900  # MW

Hydro_cap = 500  # MW
Hydro_start = 500  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Hydro_cost = 21  # $/MW
Hydro_min = 50  # MW

Nuc_cap = 5500  # MW
Nuc_start = 5375  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Nuc_cost = 20  # $/MW
Nuc_min = 2800  # %capacity

Other_cap = 1000  # MW
Other_start = 859.3  # Starting value for 2018-01-01
Other_cost = 10  # $/MW
Other_min = 100  # MW

Time = np.arange(10)

m = GEKKO()
m.time = Time

load = m.Param(np.ones_like(Time)*13000)

Nuc = m.MV(value=Nuc_start, lb=Nuc_min, ub=Nuc_cap)
Nuc.DMAX = 1413  # MW from MISO Ramp rates
Gas = m.MV(value=Gas_start, lb=Gas_min, ub=Gas_cap)
Gas.STATUS = 1
Coal = m.MV(value=Coal_start, lb=Coal_min, ub=Coal_cap)
Coal.DMAX = 2146  # MW from MISO Ramp rates
Hydro = m.MV(value=Hydro_start, lb=Hydro_min, ub=Hydro_cap)
Hydro.DMAX = 209  # MW from MISO Ramp rates
Other = m.MV(value=Other_start, lb=Other_min, ub=Other_cap)
Other.DMAX = 605  # MW from MISO Ramp rates

slack = m.Var(lb=0)
Cost = m.Var(value=0)
CostMWh = m.Var(value=0)

m.Equation(load == Nuc + Gas + Coal + Hydro + Other + slack)
m.Equation(Cost == Nuc*Nuc_cost + Gas*Gas_cost + Coal*Coal_cost +
           Hydro*Hydro_cost + Other*Other_cost + slack*1e8)
m.Equation(CostMWh == Cost/load)
m.Obj(Cost)

m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.IMODE = 5

# Initialize, if needed
#m.options.COLDSTART=2
#m.solve()

m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.options.COLDSTART=0
m.solve()
```

Comment: I see that in the model that you posted that Gas is still a m.Var(). I just used the m.options.coldstart = 1 and it didn't converge. when I then used m.options.coldstart =2 it solved super fast but It made the nuclear and Gas flat line at the max, and I don't think that it was a physical solution. My main reason for wanting to use m.MV over m.Var() is so that I can limit the DMAX. is there a way that I could limit the DMAX by using a normal Var?

Comment: Could you try using `m.options.COLDSTART=2` with `m.solve()`? Then do a second solve with `m.options.COLDSTART=0`, `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0`, and `m.solve()`. The coldstart is just for initialization. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I switched the code to use an MV for `Gas`. There is an infeasible solution message when I try to use `COLDSTART=2`. However, if I turn on the MV with `Gas.STATUS=1`, it has a successful solution.